# How could I calculate sums with group by?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am by far no expert in SQL, however I am trying my best to make the best out of it.

After cleaning and transforming data within SQL, I have a large table in SQL named *PaymentData*. A piece of my data looks like the following:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Date                     | Code                | User ID   | Payment Amount                                
2018-09-26               | 111                 | 1         | 125                                  
2018-09-26               | 122                 | 1         | 300                                 
2018-09-26               | 177                 | 1         | 150                                
2018-09-26               | 116                 | 1         | 130                                  
2018-09-26               | 118                 | 1         | 180                                
2018-09-26               | 111                 | 2         | 290                                 
2018-09-26               | 122                 | 2         | 200                                
2018-09-26               | 188                 | 2         | 200                                
2018-09-26               | 199                 | 2         | 310
```

Note that the dataset is somehow recurrent. Users get paid each month and these payments are allocated to certain allocation codes. So it is quite possible that, for example, user 1 has the same amounts and codes at 2018-10-26. But is also possble that a certain user has just a few (or more) codes and different payment amounts in another month.

Therefore, I would like to create a new table that groups the data by ID and Date and then takes the aggregate sum by certain codes. For example, I would like to have a column that sums the payment amounts of code 111 and 122 as X, another column Y that sums only the amount for 177 grouped by ID and Date and so on. Something like this, with only user 1 and 2:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Date                     | X                   | Y         | User ID                               
2018-09-26               | 425                 | 150       | 1                                                                
2018-09-26               | 490                 | 0         | 2
```

Briefly:

The new table creates columns that contain an accumulated amount based on a list of codes, grouped by date and ID. For example, in column X there is an added amount of the codes 111 and 112 per Date and ID, in column Y there is an summed amount based on for example 5 other codes per Date and ID and so on.

What is the best way to aggregate this so that in principle I can only pass my list of codes per column to SQL so that it processes it neatly for me?

Comment: I wouldn't use a new table for this, but instead [use a view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-view-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: @scsimon I edited my post with a desired result. Maybe it could help the explanation..

Comment: dude you really have to stop with the spaces in the variable names!!

Answer (score 3):

You can use conditional aggregation here

```
select
    [Date]
    ,X = sum(case when Code in (111,222) then [Payment Amount] end)
    ,Y = sum(case when Code in (177) then [Payment Amount] end)
    ,[User ID]
from
    SomeTable
group by
   [Date], [User ID]
```

Or using `IIF`

```
select
    [Date]
    ,X = sum(iif(Code in (111,222),[Payment Amount],0))
    ,Y = sum(iif(Code = 177,[Payment Amount],0))
    ,[User ID]
from
    SomeTable
```

And instead of storing it in another table, just create a view.

```
create view MyViewName
as
select
    [Date]
    ,X = sum(case when Code in (111,222) then [Payment Amount] end)
    ,Y = sum(case when Code in (177) then [Payment Amount] end)
    ,[User ID]
from
    SomeTable
```

And then call it...

```
select * from MyViewName
```

Comment: wow... we answered at the same time.!  oh wait... it says I beat you by 1 second?

Comment: haha @Hogan i suspect they use `WITH TIES` or `DENSE_RANK` in their logging!

Comment: but I have the tailing :48 -- you can hover over where it says "answered 1 min ago" and see the timestamp

Comment: @scsimon May I ask if there would be a key difference whether I use ELSE 0 or not?

Comment: You win @Hogan ZULU doesn't lie hahaha

Comment: @Jonathan -- it depends on how you are set up to handle nulls.  you might get a warning message without the else on some platforms (probably not on sql server because it never complains)

Comment: The result would be the same @Jonathan but explicit never hurts! Note, the `esle` is implict here as `else null`

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE VIEW STUFF AS

SELECT
   [Date],
   SUM(CASE WHEN CODE IN ('111','122') THEN [Payment Amount] ELSE 0 END AS x, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN CODE = '177' THEN [Payment Amount] ELSE 0 END AS y,
   [user id]
FROM PaymentData
GROUP BY [Date], [user id]
```

Comment: Naming the view `STUFF`? I don't think this is a good practice.

Comment: @Sami -- clearly a paceholder since I have no knowledge of business context.

Comment: Name it `Foo` then. Nah I just write a comment for that.

Comment: @Sami -- I did.  I just spell it different. :D

Comment: @Hogan, Can I use this at sql server?

Comment: @Jonathan -- should work fine.  are you getting an error?

Comment: @Hogan , Some of my codes are labeled with the # sign, like #323 and some don't. So, running the code gives me the error: Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value ''#323' to the data type int

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation like

```
CREATE TABLE T
    ([Date] datetime, [Code] int, [User ID] int, [Payment Amount] int)
;

INSERT INTO T
    ([Date], [Code], [User ID], [Payment Amount])
VALUES
    ('2018-09-26 00:00:00', 111, 1, 125),
    ('2018-09-26 00:00:00', 122, 1, 300),
    ('2018-09-26 00:00:00', 177, 1, 150),
    ('2018-09-26 00:00:00', 116, 1, 130),
    ('2018-09-26 00:00:00', 118, 1, 180),
    ('2018-09-26 00:00:00', 111, 2, 290),
    ('2018-09-26 00:00:00', 122, 2, 200),
    ('2018-09-26 00:00:00', 188, 2, 200),
    ('2018-09-26 00:00:00', 199, 2, 310)
;

SELECT [Date],
       [User ID],
       SUM(CASE WHEN Code IN (111, 122) THEN [Payment Amount] ELSE 0 END) X,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Code = 177 THEN [Payment Amount] ELSE 0 END) Y
FROM T
GROUP BY [Date], [User ID];
```

**Returns:**

```
+---------------------+---------+-----+-----+
|        Date         | User ID |  X  |  Y  |
+---------------------+---------+-----+-----+
| 26/09/2018 00:00:00 |       1 | 425 | 150 |
| 26/09/2018 00:00:00 |       2 | 490 |   0 |
+---------------------+---------+-----+-----+
```

**[Demo](https://rextester.com/MDXC28792)**

---

Update:

According to your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53072540/how-could-i-calculate-sums-with-group-by/53072725#comment93044357_53072706), the `Code` datatype is not int so you could change

```
       SUM(CASE WHEN Code IN ('111', '122') THEN [Payment Amount] ELSE 0 END) X,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Code = '177' THEN [Payment Amount] ELSE 0 END) Y
```

Comment: you know... his example shows user id as the last column.  (actually Nice answer including test data is a nice touch)